# Imacros extracting

Tags: imacros

Ji, just a quick question:
Why does that not working properly?

```
var extract = iimGetLastExtract();
  if (extract == "#EANF#") {
    break;
    };


    var extractMacro = "CODE:";
    extractMacro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=scraper.txt" + "\n";
  var retcode = iimPlay(extractMacro);
```

So i want to check if last extract is null and if it is, then break the loop. I want to save !extract to file too, but im getting blank "".

Thats my scraping .iim

```
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ONMOUSEDOWN:return<SP>rwt(this,'','','','{{i}}','* extract=href
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code/logic, it should work

```
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ONMOUSEDOWN:return<SP>rwt(this,'','','','{{i}}','* extract=href);
var extract = iimGetLastExtract();
while (extract != "#EANF#")
{
iimSet("extract",extract);
iimPlay("CODE:ADD !EXTRACT {{extract}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=scraper.txt");
}
```

Comment: It says: "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal, line NaN (Error code: -991)"

Comment: Check your Extract tag, I can see the open braces '(' which don't have any closed braces..   `TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ONMOUSEDOWN:return<SP>rwt(this,'','','','{{i}}','* extract=href`